# SQL cPK FK table relationship design trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and databases but have been tasked with creating a a few tables to hold information.
I am having trouble with how to best approach this.

**Table A**  `/* Populated by Flat csv file in SSMS-2016 */`

```sql
Col1(name), Col2(ArrayX,cPK), Col3(ArrayY,cPK), Col4(subname)
 /* two are required to identify a row. 1,000,000 rows */
```

**Goal:** I want to add a description to each row without repeating endlessly a block of text
where I might have 10,000 rows needing the same description text.

Example

```
**Table A**

Name, ArrayX, ArrayY, Subname
Red,  1, 1, Crayon
Red,  1, 2, Car
Red,  1, 3, Ball
Blue, 2, 1, Ball
Blue, 2, 2, Earth

**Table B**

Name(PK), Descriptions(Text)
Blue, "color, sky, azul, rainbow"
Red, "color, fire, hot, sun, rainbow"
Green, "(null value)"
```

I'd like an End User to be able to search

```sql
Select *
From Table A 
where Name like %color% AND Subname like %car%`

And SQL returns: `Red, car, "color, fire, hot, sun"`
```

or

```sql
where Name like %rainbow%
```

And SQL returns:

```
name, subname, table2(descriptions)
Red,  Crayon, "color, fire, hot, sun, rainbow" 
Red,  Car,    "color, fire, hot, sun, rainbow" 
Red,  Ball,   "color, fire, hot, sun, rainbow" 
Blue, Ball    "color, sky, azul, rainbow"
Blue, Earth   "color, sky, azul, rainbow"
```

Importantly, Table A Col(Name) should key the descriptions for all items of the same value which saves the repetition and storage required for the [text] field.

I'm guessing a complex view will get me here, but also id like to be able to input descriptions as such that

```sql
Update Table B        /* this can be manual as the number of unique items for Table1 Col(Name) is low */
set Description = "color, fire, hot, sun, rainbow"
Name = red
```

So at this point, I think Im stuck on creating a search or procedure that would give me join described above.
I know I'll need `where table A Name = Table B Name` But I haven't figured that out yet.

Is how I'm going about this making sense? Should I create an Identity on the first table as a PK to link to table B? If I do that, can I auto-fill Table B Col(name)?

Thanks for getting this far and living with the pseudo-code for a moment. I have a new respect for database developers!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do below steps:

1. As per normalized design, TableB should have the descriptions, intead of repeating the descriptions in the TableA.
2. Create a view, which joins TableA and TableB based on Name.

```sql
SELECT a.Name, a.ArrayX, a.ArrayY,a.SubName,b.Descriptions
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.Name = b.Name;
```

2. Create Non-clustered index on Name column for TableA and clustered index on Name column on TableB for getting good performance on the JOIN.
3. Now, end user search can be on top of the view, instead of TableA
4. As you told, as the number of rows are less in TableB, you can directly insert or update color values in the TableB manually.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like I am close and that join is what I'll try Monday.